# How to disable the highlight on previous clicked menu while click next menu using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some menu in my pages and initially the landing page menu is highlighted but when i am moving to next menu the previous landing page highlight is still there where it should remove while swapping the menu. I am using Angular.js and angular ui-router for this.

Here is my code:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.setting')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.setting.cat" >Settings</a></li>
 <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.users')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.users.view" >User Info</a></li>
```

My config file is given below.

route.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('connector',['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker','ngMessages','ngCapsLock','ui.bootstrap','ngFileUpload','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', { 
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
              controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', { 
        url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.setting', { 
        url: '/setting',
        templateUrl: 'view/setting.html',
        controller: 'adminSettingController'
      })

    .state('dashboard.setting.cat', { 
        url: '/manage_category',
        templateUrl: 'view/manage_category.html',
        controller: 'adminCatCategoryController'
      })

    .state('dashboard.setting.subcat', {
        url: '/manage_subcategory',
        templateUrl: 'view/manage_subcategory.html',
        controller: 'adminSubcatCategoryController'
      })
});
```

Here initially my `Home` menu is highlighted when I am clicking on `settings` menu the `Home` menu highlight should disable but in my case its not happening like this here both are showing highlight after click on second menu.

Here I need when user will click on any menu that will only highlight and landing page menu will highlight initially.same code working for `angular-1.4.6` and `angularuirouter-0.2.8` but I am using `angular-1.5.9` and `angularuirouter-0.3.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this

JS:

```
.run(function ($state,$rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
 })
```

HTML:

```
<li class="{{$state.current.name == 'dashboard.setting'?'active open':''}}">
  <a ui-sref="dashboard.setting.cat" >Settings</a>
</li>
```

Comment: and yeah you could use ng-class too!!

Comment: I updated my post .same code working for angular-1.4.6 and angularuirouter-0.2.8 but I am using angular-1.5.9 and angularuirouter-0.3.2 and here its not working.

Comment: @satya have you injected `$state` dependency in your controller?

Comment: yes, see this `dashboard.controller('dashboardController',function($scope,$http,$state,$window){`

Comment: Its the version problem I think because same code working in the earlier version like I mentioned above.

Comment: May be, you could try `$state.current.name` its works fine in all versions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145522/discussion-between-satya-and-the-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. All parent states are considered active when their child is active. So `dashboard` is active whenever `dashboard.setting` or `dashboard.users` is active. You need an alternative method for highlighting your menu items, as the_mishra pointed out.

Comment: I have also mentioned this same code is working as per expected in eariler version also.